# Correlated subqueries. Count Visits after Last Purchase Date

Tags: mysql, clickhouse

I'm pretty new to SQL and have been trying to solve this task for a while...still no luck. I would appreciate if someone here could help me out.

I have a database with columns:

- ClientID
- VisitID
- Date
- PurchaseID (array)
- etc.

What I'm trying to achieve is to retrieve a list containing the following data:

- ClientID
- Last Visit Date
- First Visit Date
- Last Purchase Date
- Visits Count
- Purchases Count
- Visits After Last Purchase Count

When trying to retrieve a value for `Visits After Last Purchase Count` this is where I am stuck.

```
SELECT 
ClientID, 
FirstVisit, 
LastVisit, 
LastPurchaseDate, 
Visits, 
Purchases, 
VisitsAfterPurchase
FROM 
(
SELECT 
    h.ClientID, 
    max(h.Date) AS LastVisit, 
    min(h.Date) AS FirstVisit, 
    count(VisitID) AS Visits
FROM s7_visits AS h 
WHERE Date > '2017-12-01'
GROUP BY h.ClientID
LIMIT 100
) 
ANY LEFT JOIN 
(
SELECT 
    d.ClientID, 
    max(d.Date) AS LastPurchaseDate, 
    sum(length(d.PurchaseID)) AS Purchases, 
    sum(
    (
        SELECT count(x.VisitID)
        FROM s7_visits AS x 
        WHERE x.ClientID = d.ClientID
        HAVING x.Date >= max(d.Date)
    )) AS VisitsAfterPurchase
FROM s7_visits AS d 
WHERE (length(PurchaseID) > 0) AND (Date > '2017-12-01')
GROUP BY d.ClientID
) USING (ClientID)
```

The database system I'm using is [Yandex ClickHouse](https://clickhouse.yandex/).
The `USING` syntax is absolutely normal for ClickHouse. It is used instead of `ON` clause in other RDBMSs.

This query is giving me the following error:

> ```
> DB::Exception: Column Date is not under aggregate function and not in GROUP BY..
> ```

Sample Data:

```
  +----------+---------+------------+------------+
  | CliendID | VisitID |    Date    | PurchaseID |
  +----------+---------+------------+------------+
  |      123 |     136 | 01.12.2017 |            |
  |      123 |     522 | 05.12.2017 |            |
  |      123 |     883 | 08.12.2017 |            |
  |      123 |     293 | 09.12.2017 | ['345']    |
  |      123 |     278 | 12.12.2017 |            |
  |      123 |     508 | 12.12.2017 |            |
  |      123 |     562 | 15.12.2017 |            |
  |      123 |     523 | 21.12.2017 |            |
  |      456 |     736 | 29.11.2017 |            |
  |      456 |     417 | 03.12.2017 |            |
  |      456 |     950 | 04.12.2017 |            |
  |      456 |     532 | 05.12.2017 | ['346']    |
  |      456 |     880 | 09.12.2017 |            |
  |      456 |     296 | 12.12.2017 |            |
  |      456 |     614 | 15.12.2017 |            |
  +----------+---------+------------+------------+
```

And the result should be:

```
  +----------+-----------------+------------------+--------------------+--------------+-----------------+----------------------------------+
  | ClientID | Last Visit Date | First Visit Date | Last Purchase Date | Visits Count | Purchases Count | Visits After Last Purchase Count |
  +----------+-----------------+------------------+--------------------+--------------+-----------------+----------------------------------+
  |      123 |      21.12.2017 |       01.12.2017 |         09.12.2017 |            8 |               1 |                                4 |
  |      456 |      15.12.2017 |       29.11.2017 |         05.12.2017 |            7 |               1 |                                3 |
  +----------+-----------------+------------------+--------------------+--------------+-----------------+----------------------------------+
```

Comment: no one wants to see a query that doesn't work, show us your tables and what you want

Comment: what is ANY LEFT JOIN , and how does s7_visits.Date represent lastvisit and LastPurchaseDate

Comment: @EvanCarroll Added sample data and the corresponding result I want to achieve. ANY LEFT JOIN is just a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but I'd consider the logic for the `sum((SELECT count(x.VisitID)` part. I believe the SUM should be unnecessary - the subquery should return a single value, using `max(d.Date)` for each `ClientID`. In some DBMSes, you can't include a subquery in an aggregate function.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
Unfortunately ClickHouse does not support aliases for subqueries and hence referencing. So I had to find another workaround using SELECT from subquery (with LastVisitDate) LEFT JOINed with another subquery (with LastPurchase Date) containing and then using WHERE clause "LastVisitDate < LastPurchaseDate".

Comment: Alas, another case where 3rd party software gets in the way?